# Understanding how to use cordova-plugin-dialogs documentation an example 8.0.0

Tags: cordova, plugins

I've using Cordova to build mobile apps and I think is amazing. I would like to use cordova-plugin-dialogs. I read [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-dialogs/), git [project](https://github.com/sitewaerts/cordova-plugin-document-viewer-sample-app) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cordova%20plugins%20how%20to%20use). I can't understand the next:

1. Do I need to add the code?
2. Where? Which file?
3. Do I need to modify some files or do I need to create a new file?
4. Which path?